# find first line number that meets criteria

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, indexing, find

I have a logfile that has rows of comma separated values. I need to find the line number of the first line that where the second object in the list is > 19. Problem is the csv data is string and numbers.

I have read the file in using csv.reader so it is all strings. I have not figured out how to convert the second object in each line to a number and run the test and return the line number. Based on data below I would expect to return "5"

```
some text
date, data1, data2, data3
1,2,3,4
date2, data4, data5, data6
1,20,3,5
date3, data7, data8, data9
1,200,3.5,4.5
```

---

```
import csv
Input = open('C:\\pytest\\list of lists.txt', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(Input)
for line in reader:
    print line

waldo = 19
pos = next(x for x, val in enumerate(reader) if val > waldo)
print pos
```

it does not print anything and last error line is "`StopIteration`".

Comment: Data did not post right. should be
some text/n 

date, data1, data2, data3/n

1,2,3,4/n

date2, data4, data5, data6/n

1,20,3,5/n

date3, data7, data8, data9/n

1,200,3.5,4.5/n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below.

```py
with open('C:\\pytest\\list of lists.txt', 'r') as file_handle:  
    line_count=0
    line_ = ""
    for line in file_handle: 
        line_count += 1
        line_ = line
        if int(line.split(",")[1])>19:
            break
print line_
print line_count
```

May be this is what you wanted. Please let me know.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simple linear search

```
line_number = 0
for array_from_csv_reader in csv_reader_fetched_arrays:
    try:
        second_obj_as_number = float(array_from_csv_reader[1])
        if second_obj_as_number > 19:
            break
    except Exception as e:
        line_number = line_number + 1
        continue
print (line_number) # <-- your answer
```